# Can I ignore .css files while running >$ git mergetool?

Tags: git, sass, git-merge

Our project has .scss file which we generate to .css and the generated .css files are stored in the repo.

There's no point merging our entire site's .min.css or .css.map.

When running `$ git mergetool`, can I configure it to ignore these files, whether by directory or file name or file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
.min.css
.css.map
```

to you .gitignore file. After commiting the .gitignore file with these entries you can ignore the files that have already been pushed by executing the following command

```
git rm -r --cached
git add .
```

What the above commands do is that they refresh the index file which contains your already published .min.css, .css.map files (filtered -- sortof) And then commit again after the above two commands to delete the files that are generated.

Using Git Attributes, it is possible to ignore remote changes during merge. More details are provided in the link below -

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies

Comment: This will stop tracking the files, is it possible to keep the files tracked, but ignore them just for the merge?

Comment: that's great, it solves the problem. Can you add that as an edit to the answer and I'll accept it.